# Перейти на несколько каталогов выше html

Tags: html, файлы, path

У меня есть блок видео в котором я указываю путь к этому видео. Если видео находиться в папке с проектом, то никаких проблем нет. Например я указываю такую ссылку

```
<source src="video/video.mkv" type="video/mp4">
```

И все работает, он открывает и загружает видео. Но таких видео у меня много и я не хочу их все переносить в папку с проектом. Мне нужно выйти из папки с проектом и перейти в другую находящуюся на несколько уровней выше. Я пробовала указать путь таким образом, но он не работает:

```
<source src="../../../../.././installers/films/film1/video.mkv" type="video/mp4">
```

т.е. он у меня находится по такому пути C:\installers\films\film1
а сам проект по такому C:\Project\VsCode\Python\web\my_pr\index.html

Я не намерена публиковать данный сайт, а собираюсь использовать в домашнем пользовании. Потому мне нужен именно этот путь к папке. Пожалуйста подскажите как указать верный путь к файлу?

Comment: сайт каким образом работает (запускается)? Напрямую питоном или через Апач, например?

Comment: пока никак, в данный момент просто запускается одна страничка. В дальнейшем через django. Там так же планирую кодом брать пути к папкам с видео. Но суть в том, что мне нужны конкретно эти пути. Выставлять никуда не планирую, а хочу подымать как локальный кинотеатр:) все видео у меня грузятся в эту папку и мне не удобно будет их копировать в папку с проектом. Потому если возможно хочу попадать к этой папке с фильмами.

Comment: ну вот как определитесь как будете запускать, так и пишите. Для локально запускаемой странички можно указать даже абсолютный пусть к файлу.